# Index directory of files at once not one after another in solr

Tags: solr, lucene, bigdata

I have large directory contain set of files, which I need to index in solr 4.10.0 and I don't want to index them one after another as every single indexing of file the index of solr core will be changed. Is there any method to index the whole directory once without the need to combine all these files into a big one file?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear, regardless of indexing one file at a time or all together there will be changes to the indexes.

Thanks
-Hussain

Comment: so again indexing file1 then file2 then file3 will create an initial index for file1 then change it for file2 then change it for file3, but If I have one file (F) then indexing F will create only one index without updating it a lot. I hope it's clear now!

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on your requirement now, I'll just weigh in the pros and cons
Indexing files individually, you can search them individually. So lets take an e.g.
Name: File1
Contents: File1

Similarly File2 and File3
Now post indexing if you query SOLR for keyword "file", you'll get three documents.

On the other approach if you combine all the three file and index it as one document, you'll only get one document.
It all depends on what you are trying to achieve at the end.

```
Thanks
-Hussain
```